how to select parent/collection of child entity in one query to avoid N+1 on child entity
My entities as below
@Entity
public class A {

  @ManyToOne
  private B b;
}

@Entity
public class B {

  @OneToMany
  private Set<C> c;
}

@Entity
public class C {
  ...
}

when I try
select a from A a
left outer join fetch a.b b1
left outer join fetch b1.c c1

I can see there are lot of select c...
How can I avoid multiple round trip of c in this case?
I tried to use @BatchSize on B entity as well as C collection, still see lot of round trip call
